# Programa de python compilado con pyinstaller no se ejecuta en ALGUNOS pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, console

Estoy intentando convertir un programa de python a exe con pyinstaller. El exe generado me funciona bien en 3 ordenadores y una máquina virtual pero al ejecutarlo en el ordenador de la empresa se queda la pantalla así:

[image: Pantalla negra]

Esta pantalla negra se queda para siempre.

Alguna idea de porqué no está compilando el código? Debería imprimir una frase diciendo: Idioma / Lenguage ? (esp/eng)

Esta es la primera parte del código:

```
import mkdir
from os import path

if path.isfile('utils/specs.py'):
    from utils.specs import lang
else:
    print('Idioma / Lenguage ? (esp/eng) ')
    lang = input()
    mkdir('utils')
    f = open("utils/specs.py", "w")
    f.write("lang = '" + lang + "'")
    f.close()
```

Como no existe ni la carpeta utils ni el fichero specs al ser la primera ejecución debería imprimir lo dicho anteriormente.

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar passando?

PD: comando utilizado para pyinstaller:

`pyinstaller ./iwom_automator.py --onefile --icon=logo_iwom.ico`

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Como sugerencia, todo código que compartas, idealmente debe ir como texto para que otros puedan replicar tu problema.

Comment: @Alfabravo: Hecho

Comment: muchos antivirus detectan los compilados de pyinstaller como un virus, probá desactivando el antivirus y ver si anda, porque como dijiste no anda en algunos.

Comment: @tincopasan el antivirus utilizado es el windows defender y no hay ningun aviso ni nada sobre alguna acción en el programa. Por eso me parecía tan raro.

Comment: probalo igual, no descartes la posibilidad de que sea, auqnue te parezca raro.

Comment: @tincopasan He comprobado el firewall y no está bloqueando nada. Tampoco hay ningún aviso. En el ordenador de un compañero en la misma organización le funcionaba y todos los ordenadores son de 64-bits. No se la verdad es que estoy muy atrapado ahora mismo.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta. Probaste con escribir algo en la consola y dar enter para ver que pasa?

Comment: Se crea el archivo?

Comment: @DanteS. si! i no escribe nada. Lo que le pasa es que intenta compilar el programa pero no lo hace por alguna razón (se queda cargando)

Comment: Se que mi pregunta es tonta, pero el exe se cierra inmediatamente luego de que lo ejecutes? (eso cuando no seleccionas ningun texto en el cmd, que eso lo traba). Me explique bien? O sea no pintes de blanco nada en la ventana del exe.

Comment: @DanteS. Después de ejecutar el exe se queda la pantalla de la consola (la pantalla negra) hasta el fin de los tiempos (debe intentar compilar las librerías y algo pasa ni idea) tampoco hay ningún bucle así que no puede ser culpa del programa en si.

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre las computadoras donde funcionó y la que no? Diferente sistema operativo? El archivo specs.py existía en esas y en la que no funciona no existia el archivo? etc

Comment: @DanteS. pues ninguna destacable. Mismo sistema operativo y todo. Todos los exe los he ejecutado desde la misma carpeta en todas las pruebas. Todo muy raro.